# Make the address scheme relative on api.stackexchange.com (and blog)

Tags: bug, api, blog, ssl

In my setup, for reasons unrelated to this post, http://api.stackexchange.com web-site appears to be missing most of its resources, since even though the site itself is served over the `http://` address scheme, a whole bunch of other rather mandatory Stack resources are hardlinked from `cdn.sstatic.net` with `https://` (with certs issued by [COMODO](https://twitter.com/Mcnst/status/693598122715516928) and/or Cloudflare).

The same is true of the `i.stack.imgur.com` images in the blog, e.g., https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/ has a couple of "enter image description here", and no images.  No other Stack resources appear affected.

Perhaps it's possible to implement relative addressing, `//`, in place of the absolute ones, `https://`?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. YES! You do not know how many times I wish this were likely this. Even if it's just for images using the uploading system, you do not know how much of an impact this would have!